# Asserting against html

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm specifically looking for a solution in a .net mvc environment, however this question applies to all languages and frameworks

I'm currently unit testing a HtmlHelper Extension (for those who aren't .net mvc fluent, that's a function that returns a html string)

Now my problem is that html might be valid even when strings aren't equal

Lets say I want to assert my method outputs

```
<div class="myClass" id="myId" >Hello</div>
```

However it actually outputs

```
<div id="myId" class="myClass" >Hello</div>
```

That's still valid, right?
Now I may be eating my words but I haven't seen anything around that can say these are actually equal.

I believe these are equal because they are basically the same thing when it comes to rendering in a browser.

**Is there a library out there that supports such a comparison? (Specifically c# .net; however I'm also interested in other languages)**

Comment: It's valid markup.. but it isn't a valid test. Whatever causes your method to produce different markup.. you need to test for that case too.

Comment: What do you mean by "equal" here? Clearly the two strings are not the same. Semantically they make no difference when rendered as HTML. A valid test wouldn't look at either the raw string or the rendered output - it would check for a `div` element with two attributes, one named `id` with a value of `myId`, one named `class` with a value of `myClass`, where the `div` element contains a value of `Hello`.

Comment: I disagree with you Simon, i feel the test would be valid because the output is valid, it's not appropriate to ask a developer to test every possible version of markup. Preston, I'm glad you see what I'm getting at and I agree with you, interrogating the HTML is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure but may the HtmlAgilityPack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) can help you with this. it can parse html to objects that then represent the dom of your html. in your case i guess that the dom should be the same or at least it should be much easier to compare the two results of parsing then the html.

Comment: Thanks gluix, this was the type of answer I was looking for. With this NuGet I'll be able to interrogate the HTML as Preston suggested in the comment in the question.